# Form value of radios and checkboxes are always null even if checked

Tags: angular

I followed the angular 2 cookbook recipe on dynamic forms. Everything works as expected except the radios and checkboxes. For some reason I always have a null value on radios and checkboxes even if they are checked. But the touched properties of the radios and checkboxes are true after they're checked, however pristine is also true even after I have checked.

RADIOS:

```
<input  [formControlName]="question.id" [name]="question.id" [type]="question.controlType" [id]="question.id" /> Yes
<input  [formControlName]="question.id" [name]="question.id" [type]="question.controlType" [id]="question.id" /> No
```

CHECKBOXES:

```
<div [formGroupName]="question.id">
    <div *ngFor="let sq of question.subquestions">
        <input [formControlName]="sq.id" [type]="question.controlType" [id]="sq.id"/>{{sq.text}}
    </div>
</div>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/64WR7hq259FUXaFegI45?p=preview

Comment: AFAIR you need to set a `value` for radios.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer  I tried that also. Didn't work.

Comment: Your Plunkr doesn't even display the form.

Comment: @AngularFrance I am done adding the files to plunkr. I am not able to see an output. Can you look at the plunkr and see why there is no output and then help with the issue?

Comment: Sorry, but setting up the Plunkr is your responsibility. Maybe start from a WORKING Plunkr and adapt it by including pieces of your code step by step, instead of just copy/pasting your entire files.

Comment: @AngularFrance the working plunker.  https://plnkr.co/edit/64WR7hq259FUXaFegI45?p=preview

Comment: I took a look but I can't figure why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what is going wrong. In angular 2  does not take a dynamic '[type]' as Angular 2 will be looking for a static 'input[type="checkbox"]'.